# Asp.Net Upload Imagem cloudinary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Good afternoon!
I have problems uploading images to a defined folder. As you can see, in my code I can upload to the cloudinary root, but not to a specific folder I created.

```
Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(account);

string NomeImagem = "";
string TipoImagem = "";
string Versao = "";

byte[] binData = null;
string result = string.Empty;

    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {

        if (Request.Files["FotoURL"].ContentLength > 0)
        {
            using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["FotoURL"].InputStream))
            {
                binData = b.ReadBytes(Request.Files["FotoURL"].ContentLength);
            }

            string teste = Convert.ToBase64String(binData);
            byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(binData));
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
            {
                DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("."));
                string diretorio = dir.FullName.ToString();
                try
                {
                    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                    {
                        File = new FileDescription(IdUsuario + "Perfiltemp.jpg", ms)

                    };

                    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
                    NomeImagem = uploadResult.JsonObj["public_id"].ToString();
                    TipoImagem = uploadResult.Format.ToString();
                    Versao = "v" + uploadResult.Version.ToString();

                    dados += "&FotoURL=http://res.cloudinary.com/diretor/aceleramei/image/upload/" + Versao + "/" + NomeImagem + "." + TipoImagem;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    string msg = e.ToString();
                    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                    {
                        File = new FileDescription(@"" + Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Content\\layout\\img\\300x200.gif")
                    };
                    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
                    NomeImagem = uploadResult.JsonObj["public_id"].ToString();
                    TipoImagem = uploadResult.Format.ToString();
                    Versao = "v" + uploadResult.Version.ToString();
                 //   dados += "&FotoURL=http://res.cloudinary.com/diretor/image/upload/" + Versao + "/" + NomeImagem + "." + TipoImagem;

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solução

```
  string NomeImagem = "";
            string TipoImagem = "";
            string Versao = "";
           // string Pasta = "teste";
            byte[] binData = null;
            string result = string.Empty;

                if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
                {

                    if (Request.Files["FotoURL"].ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        using (BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(Request.Files["FotoURL"].InputStream))
                        {
                            binData = b.ReadBytes(Request.Files["FotoURL"].ContentLength);
                        }

                        string teste = Convert.ToBase64String(binData);
                        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(Convert.ToBase64String(binData));
                        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
                        {
                            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("teste"));
                            string diretorio = dir.FullName.ToString();
                            try
                            {
                                var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                                {
                                    File = new FileDescription(IdUsuario + "Perfiltemp.jpg" , ms),
                                    PublicId = $"aceleramei/{System.IO.Path.GetFileName(IdUsuario)}",
                                    EagerAsync = true
                                };

                                var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);

                                NomeImagem = uploadResult.JsonObj["public_id"].ToString();

                            TipoImagem = uploadResult.Format.ToString();
                                Versao = "v" + uploadResult.Version.ToString();

                            dados += "&FotoURL=http://res.cloudinary.com/diretor/image/upload/" + Versao + "/"  + NomeImagem + "." + TipoImagem;
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                string msg = e.ToString();
                                var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                                {
                                    File = new FileDescription(@"" + Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Content\\layout\\img\\300x200.gif"),
                                    PublicId = $"aceleramei/{System.IO.Path.GetFileName("")}",
                                    EagerAsync = true
                                };
                                var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
                                NomeImagem = uploadResult.JsonObj["public_id"].ToString();
                                TipoImagem = uploadResult.Format.ToString();
                                Versao = "v" + uploadResult.Version.ToString();
                             //   dados += "&FotoURL=http://res.cloudinary.com/diretor/image/upload/" + Versao + "/" + NomeImagem + "." + TipoImagem;

                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                        {
                            File = new FileDescription(@"" + Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Content\\layout\\img\\300x200.gif"),
                            PublicId = $"aceleramei/{System.IO.Path.GetFileName("")}",
                            EagerAsync = true
                        };
                        var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
                        NomeImagem = uploadResult.JsonObj["public_id"].ToString();
                        TipoImagem = uploadResult.Format.ToString();
                        Versao = uploadResult.Version.ToString();
                        dados += "&FotoURL=";

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
                    {
                        File = new FileDescription(@"" + Server.MapPath("~") + "\\Content\\layout\\img\\300x200.gif"),
                        PublicId = $"aceleramei/{System.IO.Path.GetFileName("")}",
                        EagerAsync = true
                    };
                    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
                    NomeImagem = uploadResult.JsonObj["public_id"].ToString();
                    TipoImagem = uploadResult.Format.ToString();
                    Versao = "v" + uploadResult.Version.ToString();
                     dados += "&FotoURL=";
```